# Could not load file or assembly '<assembly_name>, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, wiki-pages, assembly-references

Create new Project with two custom class library,**signing** that assembly with key,

create one custom page, And deploy through SP designer

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="DataEntities" Namespace="SPTestHnG.DataEntities"
    Assembly="SPTestHnG.DataEntities, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

DemoPage
```

But while shown preview in browser, error:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'SPTestHnG.DataEntities,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies"

**Update** : I check GAC folder"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL" where assembly file is there

**Update 2** :: If I'm load "<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>" then also gives a error Could not load file or assembly '$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$' or one of its dependencies

Comment: There are two GACs.  c:\windows\assembly for assemblies built .NET up to 3.5 and c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly for assemblies for .NET 4.0 and up.  Which version of .NET did you use and did you check the corresponding GAC location?

Comment: I found in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL" not in assembly folder..I deploy sharepoint directly so assembly in GAC_MSIL..am i right? @Erik

Comment: Is you assembly strong name correct?  Shouldn't it have the version number and culture also?  Or, are there assemblies that your assembly is referencing that aren't deployed to the correct place?

Comment: If I'm load _"<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>"_ then also gives a error _Could not load file or assembly '$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$' or one of its dependencies_ @Erik

Comment: How are you deploying the assembly to the GAC?  Are you using Visual Studio to create a solution package?

Comment: Yes, It Just _deploy solution_ using Visual studio @Erik

Answer (score 1):

Your DLL must be declared as safe in the web.config of the Web app:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="SPTestHnG.DataEntities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="SPTestHnG.DataEntities" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" />
```

However, the best practice is to make it registered as part of a WSP deployment (Visual Studio would automatically include necessary XML declaration in the manifest.xml file of the WSP at publication time).

Comment: I checked ...in my inetpub's web.config file declare in safe control that assembly already @Evariste

Comment: Also, be sure to add the reference in SPD exactly as it appears in the web.config, e.g. `<%@ Register TagPrefix="DataEntities" Namespace="SPTestHnG.DataEntities"
    Assembly="SPTestHnG.DataEntities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" %>`